# How to make a Bootstrap modal stay onscreen without jQuery in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Now, I have an odd setup on my view. Its a form with bootstrap tabs that allows the user to cycle between 'cards' in the main web form.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Form" method="post">
    <!--Summary Modal-->
    <div class="modal" tabindex="1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Summary</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Comments</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#rfi">RFI</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#search">Knowledge</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <!--RFI card-->
            <div id="rfi" class="card container tab-pane active">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder=" ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Knowledge card-->
            <div id="search" class="card container tab-pane active">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="Search" placeholder=" ">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need the modal to appear in the top right and to always be onscreen, even if the user switches tabs. They need to be able to fill them out and then click the submit button in the modal to submit the whole form.

However, every time I build my project, the modal is nowhere to be found. I can't even find it with developer tools. My guess is that it needs to be triggered by a button, like [the other modals here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Some users [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818216/how-to-always-display-bootstrap-3-modal) say you can use jQuery to show the modal when the screen loads, but we are trying to keep jquery out of this project and use typescript. Can I do it without it, or is jQuery the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you need to remove `tabindex="1"` from the first div of the modal and change it's class to 'container', like so:

```
  <div class="container" role="dialog">
```